# How to override an Flask app's view functions

Tags: python, flask, odoo

I'm using Flask(0.11.1) along with OpenERP, and:

1. I've already have define an url rule:

```py
@app.route("/sync_order")
def sync_order(): 
   print(1)
```

2. I want to override it in other OE module:

```py
@app.route("/sync_order")
def sync_order(): 
   print(1)

# override it

@app.route("/sync_order")
def sync_order2(): 
   print(2)
```

3. but I got an error:

```py
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: sync_order
```

4. here is my current solution:

```py
@app.route("/sync_order")
def sync_order(): 
   print(1)

def sync_order2(): 
   print(2)

# change the mapping of endpoint and view functions
# print `2` now
with app.app_context() as context:
    context.app.view_functions['sync_order'] = sync_order2
```

SO HERE IS MY QUESTION:

1. Is this okay to do like that, or do I have potential problems?
2. Is there another way to override view functions?
3. don't change origin function, because if I don't have the module, the function should print

Thanks

Comment: Is it not possible to write some if statement in sync_order function and handle things differenty based on if - else conditions? I'm not sure what the use case is here, at the moment it doesnt make sense to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: I can't change ANY code in sync_order, it's the OpenERP thing. Assume I have a base module, defines lots of api(including sync_order) to handle a very complex business logic.Now I have a new module, It will change some of the business logic in sync_order, so I need to override the sync_order function, but I can't change the origin function, cause if I don't install the new module, the api can call the origin sync_order to handle origin business.I just want to change the handler of the url, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Interesting case and I'm not sure if my knowledge is sufficient to be of help here. So to summarize, you cannot change the content of sync_order function, hence you want to override the function. But is it possible to add a custom decorator to it though?

Comment: I'll use the solution above, thank you anywhere